# Is there a shiny Missingno.?

Tags: pokemon-series

I was researching about the famous Missingno. and I thought to my self "What does a shiny Missingno. look like?"

If there is a shiny Missingno? I would like to see a picture of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry, there's no shiny version of MissingNo.

[MissingNo. only appears in the non-Japan Generation I (Red, Blue, Yellow) Pokémon games](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Missingno.). Said games, being designed for the monochrome Game Boy, do not have shiny Pokémon. Therefore, MissingNo. cannot be shiny in Generation I.*

[You also cannot trade MissingNo. to Generation II (Gold, Silver, Crystal) games](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Missingno.#Trading_Missingno.). Since MissingNo. can't exist in those games, it can't be shiny in Generation II.

However, there are [other glitch Pokémon in Generation II and beyond](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_glitch_Pok%C3%A9mon#In_Generation_II), and after a quick look at some of those pages it seems reasonable several of them could be shiny.

---

* Assuming the definition of "shiny" is "the game calls this a shiny Pokémon, and displays it in a different palette". [Because Generation II uses hidden values of each Pokémon to determine whether it's shiny or not](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon#Generation_II), and these values are in the Generation I as well, you could argue the first generation *does* have shiny Pokémon -- it's just that they don't have any outward difference until they're traded to Generation II.

Comment: I was sure that Pokémon Yellow was designed for the Game Boy *Color*.

Comment: @Texenox All Generation I games had Super Game Boy support, and as you mention [the non-Japanese releases of Yellow added these features to the Game Boy Color](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Yellow_Version#Trivia). But I think it's fair to say that the first Pok&eacute;mon games were primary designed for the Game Boy, using limited 4-shade palettes in cases where color was available. My point was that shinies first appeared in Generation II to highlight the fuller color display capabilities of that engine.